# Add javascript code to Document Library default view

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library

I tried to find "Edit page" option but could not find it.

Is it possible to add some `.js` file into a specific view?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using the `Modern Experience` for your document library that does not allow javascript customization and CSS branding/theming.

> You can vote for this request **"Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library Experience"** at [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)

---

**The workaround**

To can find `Edit Page` option and add a JS/ CSS customization you should switch back to `Classic Experience` as the following:

- In your list or document library, choose Settings  Settings icon and then List Settings or Library Settings.

[image]

- Click Advanced settings and then scroll down to List experience.

[image]

- Choose `Classic experience` option.

  - Classic experience

> This option sets the experience to classic, which is the previous,
>   older experience for document libraries.

- Repeat these steps to change the experience for additional lists or document libraries.

For  more details check [Switch the default experience for lists or document libraries from new or classic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9)