# Customizing "modern experience" lists in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Is it possible to customize list form fields on NewForm/EditForm if you are using modern experience functionality? I would like to inject some JavaScript to hide certain fields if others are empty - this was fairly straightforward in SP 2013, but not so much in Office 365.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Unfortunately,** in `Modern Experience`, you can't customize the page to add JS or custom CSS as we did in classic mode, meanwhile, you can

- [Reference third-party CSS styles in SharePoint Framework web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles)
- [Use SPFx extensions to add your custom CSS to the page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
- Using 3rd party form builder like [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/)

---

**Supported customizations for Modern Experience Page**

- Custom branding like custom themes
- Adding "modern" pages programmatically
- Adding, deleting, updating client-side web parts on "modern" pages

**Unsupported customizations for Modern Experience Page**

- Custom master pages
- More extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options
- Custom page templates (layout templates) and Alternative layouts
- Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages
- Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
- Custom JavaScript embedded via User Custom Actions

---

**Check also**

- [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)
- [Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension (Hello World part 1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
- [SharePoint Framework Extensions Developer Preview](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-availability-of-sharepoint-framework-extensions-developer-preview)
- [Provision files (css, js) with SharePoint Framework](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/provision-files-css-js-with-sharepoint-framework)
- [Adding CSS Reference on Site Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/adding-css-reference-on-site-page/221352#221352)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, any suggestions on my question here : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236381/corporate-branding-classic-or-modern-experience-in-sharepoint-online. What did you do on your Site to be responsive?