# Corporate Branding : Classic or Modern experience in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage, branding

Hi we already bought our new SharePoint online E3 license and we are now task to create our Company Portal landing page that needs to be responsive for mobile device.

We are now doing some R&D and we still not decided if which between Classic or Modern experience should we use to create the portal.

I saw some post that it is not advisable to change the sharepoint online master page like what we are doing in On-Prem. If in classic, where we will put on the scripts and library to make the site responsive without touching the master page.

Need your thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks.
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use classic view instead of modern experience. Since customizing modern sites/pages has more limitations:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

And custom actions approach works on "classic" sites only, including the current publishing portals. More reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the modern page, because this version will work perfectly in the SharePoint Apps for iOS and Android. This is especially important when you are creating a corporate intranet which need to be accessable from every device.