# How do I use content editor/script editor web part for SharePoint modern site/communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, communication-site

I just want to inject JavaScript in my SharePoint list of communication site. How do i use it

Answer (score 5):

**Unfortunately,** it's **not** supported in the `Modern Experience`.

You can't customize the page to add Script Editor with JS or custom CSS as we have done in `classic mode`, meanwhile, you can go ahead with one of the following:

- [Reference third-party CSS styles in SharePoint Framework web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles)
- [Use SPFx extensions to add your custom CSS to the page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
- Using 3rd party form builder like [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/)
- Switch to the Classic Mode.

---

**Below are the Unsupported customizations for Modern Experience**

- Custom master pages
- More extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options
- Custom page templates (layout templates) and Alternative layouts
- Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages
- Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
- Custom JavaScript embedded via User Custom Actions

---

**See also**

- [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)
- [Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension (Hello World part 1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
- [SharePoint Framework Extensions Developer Preview](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-availability-of-sharepoint-framework-extensions-developer-preview)
- [Provision files (css, js) with SharePoint Framework](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/provision-files-css-js-with-sharepoint-framework)
- [Adding CSS Reference on Site Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/adding-css-reference-on-site-page/221352#221352)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I Switch to the Classic Mode, but not able to see the content editor

Comment: Welcome @Jen, What about the Script Editor Do you find it? Also, Have you enabled Publishing Feature? Have you enabled Custom script form SharePoint Admin Center? by the way, the changing this setting might take up 24 hours to take effect!